# Is it possible to restrict a custom list All Items View to only the Owners group?

Tags: permissions, list-view

I have a custom list for two vendors (I have a choice field with both vendors) and need users to be able to see all the items submitted for their respective vendor (not just the user items). I created a page for each vendor and a filtered custom view for each vendor on each page and disabled the Command bar so they can't change views (this kinda works), but if a savvy user takes the list url from the address bar they can access the entire list and all views, including the other vendors items.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using? Are you using modern experience or classic experience lists?